# "Sphere embedded in a triangle"

Tags: math, physics, game-physics

I started reading articles on game physics, and they say that sentence many times. What does it mean? Here's an example from [this](http://www.peroxide.dk/papers/collision/collision.pdf) article:

> First we check for the easy case - collision inside the triangle. If
>   this happens it must be at time t0 as this is when the sphere rests on
>   the front side of the triangle plane. *Note, this can only happen if
>   the sphere is not embedded in the triangle plane*.

Comment: The definition of `embeddedInPlane` is on page 38. It is true if the sphere moves parallel to the plane of the triangle and has at least one intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A triangle lies in a plane - there is one and only one plane which contains all 3 vertices of the triangle.  I suspect they consider a sphere to be "embedded" in the plane if it overlaps it, with bits of the sphere on each side.

When a point of collision with a triangle is detected a sphere approaching from outside the plane could have hit anywhere, but a sphere which is already in the plane and approaching from the side of the triangle will hit on one of the edges first, quite possibly right on a corner.

Thus, if the first point of contact is inside the triangle, there sphere was not inside the plane on it's approach.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by "overlaps it"? I got what you said in the second paragraph though. Edit: I get it. Thanks!